# Sin in terms of t , 0 < B < pi/2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sin(B) = t$

$0 < B < \frac{\pi}{2}$

I need to find $\cos(B)$ and $\tan(B)$

I know $\tan(B)=\large\frac{\cos(B)}{t}$, but how do I find $\cos(B)$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: As $B$ is in the first quadrant, $\cos B=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2B}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $sin^2 x + cos^2 x = 1$. Using that identity you can solve for the others.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\sin^2B+\cos^2B=1$. Now since $ 0 < B < \pi/2$ we know that $\cos B> 0$ and thus we have that $\cos B = \sqrt{1-\sin^2B}=\sqrt{1-t^2}$. We can use this to find $\tan B = \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}$.

Comment: (in this case, since you know $\cos B > 0$)

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that thanks!